# Sum each list of numerical values within a list

Tags: r, riverplot

I would like to attach values to labels in a riverplot in R

I have a list of lists of values, which is required to show flows between nodes, like this:

```
edges <- list( A= list( C= 10, E= 5 ), 
               B= list( C= 10 ), 
               C=list(D = 13, E = 7 ))
```

I am aware of a function that would reduce (or sum) one element of a list like this:
Reduce("+",edges$A)

Is there a way of reducing such a list of lists of values to a dataframe or so that I could get the sums:

```
Node Sum
A 15
B 10
C 20
D 13
E 12
```

Edit:

I just realised there is a confusion:
It looks like I need two outputs and it may be a little more complicated:
 1. if 'edges' list has a sublist with a category name, sum up 
 2. if not, get the sum of all occurences of this item

Case 1: Categories A, B, C (these are the starting nodes)
Case 2: Categories D, E (these are the end nodes in a riverplot)

I am sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your edit is not making much sense.

Comment: It may ... I am thinking on it...
I noticed that unlist(edges) gives me 
A.C A.E B.C C.D C.E 
 10   5  10  13   7 
If I could somehow sum only on the category after the dot...

Comment: I am sorry, I realised the D, E nodes will not be summed with this method and perhaps need another solution. These are end nodes and they are not part of the main list. They are the items of the sublists that need to be summed. I tried to describe my edit and the confusion in the main question

Comment: I accepted the answer. I deserve a minus myself, awfully sorry for not seing the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do

```
lapply(edges, function (x) sum(unlist(x)))
```

This returns a list. Using `sapply` will simplify the result to a vector.

Comment: I am sorry I corrected my question. I forgot about summing up D and E.
I noticed that unlist gives me 
A.C A.E B.C C.D C.E 
 10   5  10  13   7 
If I could somehow sum only on the category after the dot...

Answer (score 3):

We can also use `base R`

```
 v1 <- unlist(edges)
 tapply(v1, sub("\\..*", "", names(v1)), sum)
 # A  B  C 
 #15 10 20
```

Or in a single step

```
 r1 <- tapply(unlist(edges), rep(names(edges), lengths(edges)), FUN = sum)
 r1
 # A  B  C 
 #15 10 20
```

if we need to `sum` based on the `names` after the `.`

```
 r2 <- tapply(v1, sub("[^.]+\\.", "", names(v1)), FUN = sum)
 r2
 # C  D  E 
 #20 13 12 

 c(r1, r2)[!duplicated(c(names(r1), names(r2)))]
 # A  B  C  D  E 
 #15 10 20 13 12
```

---

Or using `aggregate/stack`

```
aggregate(values~., stack(edges), FUN = sum)
#    ind values
#1   A     15
#2   B     10
#3   C     20
```

Comment: I am sorry I corrected my question. I forgot about summing up D and E.
I noticed that unlist gives me 
A.C A.E B.C C.D C.E 
 10   5  10  13   7 
If I could somehow sum only on the category after the dot...

Comment: @JacekKotowski  In that case, you will not get the 'A' category.  Can you explain your expected output?

Comment: @ZheyuanLi  Plus one to you as well.

Comment: @JacekKotowski  I updaed the post to get the expected though I am not sure what kind of condition is this.

Comment: plus one for `stack`. nice function.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)
stack(map(edges, compose(sum, unlist)))
#   values ind
# 1     15   A
# 2     10   B
# 3     20   C
```

where `compose(sum, unlist)` is equivalent to `function(x) sum(unlist(x))`.

Comment: I am sorry I corrected my question. I forgot about summing up D and E.
I noticed that unlist gives me 
A.C A.E B.C C.D C.E 
 10   5  10  13   7 
If I could somehow sum only on the category after the dot...

Answer (score 1):

Or using your own proposed `Reduce` function:

```
unlist(lapply(edges, function(a) Reduce(sum, a)))

# A  B  C 
#15 10 20
```